# ios: Having problem with posting data to Firestore

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to post data to firebase. but when I click my button, Nothing happens. Neither data sending nor any exception occurred. I have tried many ways, and also tried new projects but problem remains same. I have tried the test code that is given on Firebase website, nothing happens.

**Here are my constants**

```
let THOUGHTS_REF = "thoughts"

let CATEGORY = "category"

let NUM_COMMENTS = "numComments"

let NUM_LIKES = "numLikes"

let THOUGHT_TXT = "thoughtTxt"

let TIMESTAMP = "timestamp"

let USERNAME = "username"
```

**Here is Enum for ThoughtCategory **

```
enum ThoughtCategory: String {

    case serious = "serious"
    case funny = "funny"
    case crazy = "crazy"
    case popular = "popular"

}
```

**here is code behind VIEW:**

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseFirestore

class AddThoughtVC: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {


    //Outlets
    @IBOutlet weak var segmentControl: UISegmentedControl!
    @IBOutlet weak var usernameTxt: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var thoughtTxt: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var postBtn: UIButton!

    //Variables
    private var categorySelected = ThoughtCategory.funny.rawValue


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        thoughtTxt.delegate = self

        postBtn.layer.cornerRadius = 4
        thoughtTxt.layer.cornerRadius = 4
        thoughtTxt.text = "My random thought..."
        thoughtTxt.textColor = UIColor.lightGray
    }

    func textViewDidBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
        textView.text = ""
        textView.textColor = UIColor.darkGray
    }

    @IBAction func categoryChanged(_ sender: Any) {

        switch segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex {
        case 0:
            categorySelected = ThoughtCategory.funny.rawValue
        case 1:
            categorySelected = ThoughtCategory.serious.rawValue
        default:
            categorySelected = ThoughtCategory.crazy.rawValue
        }

    }

    @IBAction func postBtnTapped(_ sender: Any) {

        guard let username = usernameTxt.text else { return }

            Firestore.firestore().collection(THOUGHTS_REF).addDocument(data: [

            CATEGORY : categorySelected,
            NUM_COMMENTS : 0,
            NUM_LIKES : 0,
            THOUGHT_TXT : thoughtTxt.text,
            TIMESTAMP : FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
            USERNAME : username


        ]) { (err) in
            if let err = err {
                debugPrint("Error adding document: \(err)")
            } else {
                self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
            }
        }

    }

}
```

**Here is an error in Log file**

> 2018-10-30 22:58:50.091529+0500 RNDM[802:11061] [BoringSSL]
>   nw_protocol_boringssl_get_output_frames(1301) [C3.1:2][0x7fdb1051de90]
>   get output frames failed, state 8196
>
> 2018-10-30 22:58:50.091719+0500 RNDM[802:11061] [BoringSSL]
>   nw_protocol_boringssl_get_output_frames(1301) [C3.1:2][0x7fdb1051de90]
>   get output frames failed, state 8196
>
> 2018-10-30 22:58:50.092369+0500 RNDM[802:11061] TIC Read Status
>   [3:0x0]: 1:57 2018-10-30 22:58:50.092511+0500 RNDM[802:11061] TIC Read
>   Status [3:0x0]: 1:57

Comment: check the security rules on the Firestore console . I think your application is not authorised to access the Firestore. Check the Rules tab of the console.

Comment: thanks, problem was solved

Comment: @Usama How did you solved the problem? I have the same issue. Security rules are set to public3

Comment: Any more information on how this was resolved?

Comment: I just changed security rules to public @BradThomas
`Read: true
Write: true`

Answer (score 0):

```
Check Firestore rules
rules_version = '1';

service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```